# Adding glyphicon icons to form fields

Tags: parsley.js

I'm wanting to add icons to form fields like bootstrap has: http://getbootstrap.com/css/?#forms-control-validation

I was able to get the class to display properly on the form-group by adjusting the options:

```
successClass: 'has-success',
        errorClass: 'has-error',
        classHandler: function (_el) {
            return _el.$element.closest('.form-group');
        }
```

but i'm unable to figure out the best way to add the error or checkmark glyphicon. I assume it may have something to do with the errorWrapper / errorContainer but there isn't one for successWrapper/container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up coming up with something else:

```
var bootstrapParsleyOptions = {
    successClass: 'has-success has-feedback',
    errorClass: 'has-error has-feedback',
    classHandler: function (_el) {
        return _el.$element.closest('.form-group');
    }
};

$.extend(true, ParsleyUI, {
    enableBootstrap: function () {
        $(".form-control-feedback").removeClass('glyphicon-ok').removeClass('glyphicon-remove');

        window.Parsley.on('form:init', function () {
            $(this.$element).find(".form-control-feedback").removeClass('glyphicon-ok').removeClass('glyphicon-remove');
        });

        window.Parsley.on('field:validated', function () {
            var element = this.$element;
            if (this.validationResult == true) {
                $(element).siblings(".form-control-feedback").removeClass('glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
                $(element).siblings(".sr-only").text("(success)");
            } else {
                $(element).siblings(".form-control-feedback").removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
                $(element).siblings(".sr-only").text("(error)");
            }
        });
    },
    clearBootstrap: function () {
        $(".form-control-feedback").removeClass('glyphicon-ok').removeClass('glyphicon-remove');
    }
});
```

To enable it:

```
$("#form").parsley(bootstrapParsleyOptions);
ParsleyUI.enableBootstrap();
```

To reset it:

```
$("#form").parsley(bootstrapParsleyOptions).reset();
ParsleyUI.enableBootstrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that you can obtain what you want with CSS, something like

```
.parsley-success::before { content: '√'; }
```

Comment: I'll look into this. I do not actually see the class since I am overriding the class to make it fit bootstrap with the has-success and has-error on the form-group elements